# Portal container is not type correct

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hello I have a problem with the portal. I am using react with Typescript. The problem is that I create an element in the use-portal, but React wants the ReactNode. How can I create some walkaround except using "any"?

I get an error

```
Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactNode'.
  Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, type, props
```

Portal.tsx

```
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

import { usePortal } from "./use-portal";

interface PortalProps {
  rootId: string;
  children: JSX.Element;
}

const Portal: React.FC<PortalProps> = ({ rootId, children }) => {
  const portalContainer = usePortal(rootId);
  return createPortal(portalContainer, children);
};

export default Portal;
```

use-portal.tsx

```
const createRootElement = (id: string): Element => {
  const rootContainer = document.createElement("div");
  rootContainer.setAttribute("id", id);
  return rootContainer;
};

const addRootElement = (rootElem: Element): void => {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll("body > div");
  if (elements.length > 0) {
    const lastElement = elements[elements.length - 1];
    document.body.insertBefore(rootElem, lastElement);
  } else {
    document.body.append(rootElem);
  }
};

export const usePortal = (id: string): Element => {
  const existingElement = document.getElementById(id);
  const portalElement = existingElement ?? createRootElement(id);
  if (!existingElement) {
    addRootElement(portalElement);
  }
  return portalElement;
};
```

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Comment: Errors occurs in the Portal.tsx

Comment: Try `createPortal(children, portalContainer)` instead.

Comment: @Oblosys It works, what a rookie mistake :). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved, the problem was the order, I had to swap children and portalContainer in createPortal. The correct Portal component:

```
const Portal: React.FC<PortalProps> = ({ rootId, children }) => {
  const portalContainer = usePortal(rootId);
  return createPortal(children, portalContainer);
};
```

Rookie mistake :)